# Is it necessary to have one's driver license in one's posession while driving in Oregon?

Tags: united-states, driving, any-jurisdiction, oregon

In some jurisdictions, it is necessary to carry one's driver license at all times while driving. In others, it is only required to be licensed; it can be proven later after being pulled over, perhaps by taking the license to a police station within a certain amount of time.

What is the requirement in Oregon? (Answers from other jurisdictions are welcome as well.)

Comment: FWIW, DAs will often voluntarily dismiss charges for not having a license if a license valid at the time of the ticket is later produced, even if the law authorizes a charge in those circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to carry it with you.

[ORS 807.570](https://oregon.public.law/statutes/ors_807.570)
(1)A person commits the offense of failure to carry a license or to present a license to a police officer if the person either:
(a)Drives any motor vehicle upon a highway in this state without a license, driver permit or out-of-state license **in the person’s possession**

Footnote: It would sure be nice if the legislature would amend this to allow [digital licenses](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212940) (some states have already done this).